# Cannot determine source of Excel OneDrive data source in Powerapps

Tags: excel, datasource, powerapps

I have used a table in an Excel workbook stored on OneDrive as a data source in Powerapps. The data source is listed as 'tblALL' (which is the name as the table), and OneDrive for Business. But is there nowhere that I can find the name of the *workbook* where this data resides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting one - the short answer is no - there's no place where we can find the name of the workbook where the table is stored. The app only contains a "dataset name" which is a key that the connector can use to find the actual file (workbook), and there's no way to retrieve which file that key maps to. You can consider creating a new feature request in the [PowerApps Ideas board](https://aka.ms/powerapps-ideas) for this.

One possible way to find out which file contains a given table is to make a change to that table (i.e., using the app, first add a new record, then remove it) - and go over the workbooks that you have stored in OneDrive to see which one was updated more recently. Granted, this may take some time if you have multiple folders where the workbook can be stored, but that was the only way I could find today.